# NLog OnNewLogFile Handler?

Tags: nlog

Is there any event handler or similar that I can hook into, to run some code every time NLog starts a new Log File?

---

I have an NLog Config like this:

```
    <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File"
            fileName="[stuff]"
            layout="[more Stuff]"
            maxArchiveFiles="4"
            archiveAboveSize="102400"  />
```

And I'd kinda like to add some meta-data at the start of every log file (version number, Machine Name, etc. so that every log file comes complete with some contextual information)

I don't expect to be able to configure this text in NLog itself, but I'm hoping that I can tell NLog to run a certain method everytime it's going to create a new Log File.

Is this a thing?

Comment: Feature Request raised on NLog Github: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/3814#issuecomment-589579035

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are really looking for the **Header**-Layout on the FileTarget.

```
<target name="logfile" xsi:type="File">
         <header>--- ${assembly-version} started on ${longdate} ---</header>
</target>
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target

Some combine it with `archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"` because the Header is only printed when file is created (ensure application restarts will create new file).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **FileSystemWatcher**.

FileSystemWatcher is watching specific (which you want it) directory, If new file created, handle this event with FileSystemWatcher

For more details : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

Another partial solution to the "What version?" aspect of this problem could come from:

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AssemblyVersion-Layout-Renderer